# How to avoid duplicate dom in function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
 if (countRefinements > 1)
    {
        if (refinementType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() != "micro")
        {
            <div class="refinementContainer refinementmacro">
                //some functions
            </div>
        }

        else
        { 
            switch (Enumerable.Range(1, 17).Contains(countRefinements))
            {
                case true:
                    <div class="refinementContainer classIfConditionIsTrue refinementmicro">
                       //some functions
                    </div>
                    break;

                case false:
                    <div class="refinementContainer refinement@(refinementType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())" data-dimension="@(refinementType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())">
                        <div class="refinementContainer classIfConditionIsFalse refinementmicro">
                            //some functions
                        </div>
                    break;
                    </div>
                    break;
            }


        }
    }
```

I have this situation. I need to avoid to duplicate dom into the code. The only change is the add of one class if the condition into the switch is TRUE. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why on earth are you using a `switch(bool) case true case false` instead of an `if else`?

Comment: What do you mean _duplicate dom_? (there is no duplicate html generated in your view)

Comment: Additionally, why `Enumerable.Range(1,x).Contains(y)` instead of `y < x`? This code feels so overengineered to a point where I would personally re-evaluate every decision that was made in it to confirm that the code is actually necessary and efficient. But that would require contextual knowledge of the application and the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a variable to hold your CSS classes. Then append to this variable depending on your conditions. Finally, render it only once.

The following example (Razor) only demostrates how to render "classIfConditionIsTrue" or "classIfConditionIsFalse" depending on one condition:

```
@{
   // TODO: handle "macro", create outer div if false
   string cssClasses = "refinementContainer refinementmicro";
   if (countRefinements >= 1 && countRefinements <= 17) {
       cssClasses += " classIfConditionIsTrue";
   }
   else {
       cssClasses += " classIfConditionIsFalse";
   }
}

<div class="@cssClasses">
    // some functions
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Razor syntax to simplify the code. The idea is to check the suitable class name before it is rendered as HTML code.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

```
@{
    //declare this on top of your cshtml page
    var className = "refinementContainer";

    if (countRefinements > 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(refinementType.ToString()))
    {
        if (refinementType.ToString().ToLower() != "micro")
        {
            className += " refinementmacro";
        }
        else if (countRefinements >= 1 && countRefinements <= 17)
        {
            className += " classIfConditionIsTrue refinementmicro";
        }
        else
        {
            className += " classIfConditionIsFalse refinementmicro";
        }
    }
}
<div class="@(className)">
   //some functions
</div>
```